# Array Multiplication in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiplication

I am trying to multiply child array elements. Can you please have a look below code and let me know if we can do more optimization.

Note:- I want to push the multiplied value of child arrays in another array.

Can you please help me with this.

```
var arr1 = [
    [3, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5]
]

var sumArr = [];
for (var row = 0; row < arr1.length; row++) {
    var fullRow = arr1[row];
    var val = 1;
    for (var col = 0; col < fullRow.length; col++) {
        val *= fullRow[col];
    }
    sumArr.push(val);

}
console.log(sumArr);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimization"?

Comment: This is related to javascript

Comment: What is the expected output? Does this code work?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use `map` and `reduce` as follows:

```js
const arr1 = [ [3, 2]
             , [2, 3]
             , [4, 5]
             ];

const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;

const product = arr => arr.reduce(multiply, 1);

const sumArr = arr1.map(product);

console.log(sumArr);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "optimization" but is this what you're looking for?

Comment: This doesn't deal well with an edge case of [] as it will return 1 instead of 0

Comment: It's supposed to return 1 because that is the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of multiplication. It's not supposed to return 0 because that is the [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element) of multiplication.

Comment: The multiplication of no elements is 1?

Comment: If you asked me what is the product of nothing I would answer nothing.

Comment: For multiplication 1 is "nothing". The "nothing" that you are referring to is the identity element. This makes sense because when you convert numbers into their logarithms then multiplication becomes addition and 1 becomes 0. However, 0 becomes undefined.